# Матрица очередей JAVA

Tags: java

Необходимо создать матрицу, элементами которой является очередь<строка>. Не получается инициализировать ее.

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<LinkedList<String>>> letters = new ArrayList<ArrayList<LinkedList<String>>>();
    int size = 26;
    letters.ensureCapacity(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        letters.get(i).ensureCapacity(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j)
            letters.get(i).get(j).add("" + i + j);
    System.out.println(letters);
```

Comment: Но ведь очередь это `Queue`. А у вас что-то какая-то эмуляция ассоциативного многомерного массива........ разве не надо вам что-то типа `Queue<String>[][] strings = new LinkedList[4][4];` ?

Comment: `ensureCapacity` увеличивает только размер внутреннего массива `ArrayList`. Вам надо явно в цикле создать через `new ArrayList()` и добавить в `letters` каждую строку матрицы, и потом еще `new LinkedList()` для каждого элемента.