# Структура данных "очередь строк" в виде класса

Tags: c#

Нужно реализовать структуру данных «очередь строк» в виде класса (набора классов). Стандартные классы-коллекции .NET не использовать, в качестве внутренней структуры для хранения данных использовать исключительно массивы.

Если честно, я пока вообще не понимаю, что от меня требуется.
Заранее спасибо

Comment: Массив для стека подошел бы, но для очереди FIFO как то дубово.

Comment: Вам нужно почитать о типах контейнеров - список, очередь, стек (list, queue, stack).

Comment: Да и массивы есть не только статические но и динамические.

Comment: *я пока вообще не понимаю, что от меня требуется* — так уточните у того, кто ставил вам задачу. и этого человека надо искать явно не на [ru.so].

Comment: Если это практическая задача, то объясните, чем вас не устраивают стандартные контейнеры (производительность? память? недостаток фич?) Если учебная, решайте сами, за вас мы выучиться программировать не сможем.

Comment: с Java не получилось? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/532387/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9-java